# Looking for a prolog interpreter

Tags: prolog, logic, logic-programming

I am new to prolog and to try some logic programs I am looking for a nice prolog interpreter.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Please be specific. On which platform? unix/linux/windows/osx? .....

Comment: Mac OSx ... i am trying sicstus

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BProlog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BProlog)
[Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECLiPSe) 
[SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org)
[SICStus](http://www.sics.se/isl/sicstuswww/site/index.html)
[Gnu-Prolog](http://www.gprolog.org)
[Visual Prolog](http://www.visual-prolog.com)

And if you want to play around without installations possibly

[Ideone](http://ideone.com)

There are more, but these should be enough.

Comment: I tried Gnu-Prolog and Swi-prolog (Sicstus seems to be not free) and I definitely enjoy using Swi-prolog with Eclipse. I a using the eclipse PDT plugin available at [link](http://sewiki.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/pdt/docs/v2.1/download) and it's just great! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Gprolog and sicstus prolog are the big ones. Also, use Google the next time.

Comment: Hello Andreas, Thanks for your answer. Of course I googled it but wanted to have reason to choose one instead of another ... I will definitely try Gprolog

Comment: JUst to confirm that SWi-prolog was the best choice . It also includes a debugger. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An interesting and peculiar viewpoint come with [YieldProlog](http://yieldprolog.sourceforge.net/).

What like to me it's the fact that using it you can embed logic programs in your pages (using JavaScript)...

OTOH, it's not much useful if you need to debug your logic...

Comment: I am also interested in debugging the logic, if the interpreter (or IDE) provides it ...